# how to send context with intent to 2 classes?

Tags: java, android, android-intent

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    PlacesMapActivity.class,AddItemizedOverlay.class);
            // Sending user current geo location
            i.putExtra("user_latitude", Double.toString(gps.getLatitude()));
            i.putExtra("user_longitude", Double.toString(gps.getLongitude()));

            // passing near places to map activity
            i.putExtra("near_places", nearPlaces);
            // staring activity
            startActivity(i);
        }
```

i wanna send the intent to PlacesMapActivity.class and AddItemizedOverlay.class, how can i do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Construct two individual Intents and send them.